# Filtering markers doesnot show infowindow in second filter

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to filter the markers based on categories from the database. The infowindow are displayed on window load.

The infowindow loads perfectly in the first filter, that is when i select a category from the select dropdown, the markers are filtered with the infowindow on their top. However, the second filter acts strange, the infowindow doesnot get displayed on the markers on second consecutive filter.

Heres how i've filtered the markers:

```
filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
         #markers1 is a list of markers 
        marker = gmarkers1[i]; #gmarkers is an array of different markers
        infowindow_content = InfoWindow1[i];

        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
            infowindow_content.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am also able to get the infowindow contents in the console. If this snippets of code is not enough i am glad to upload the entire code of mine. Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**
Rest of my code:

```
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var InfoWindow1 = [];
// Our markers
markers1 = [
    {% for d in data %}
        [ '{{d.current_address_gr}}', {{ d.current_address_lat }}, {{ d.current_address_lng }},"{% profile_name_tag d.profile.id "False" "False" %}", '{{ d.current_department.name }}', '{{d.employee_level.name}}' ], 
    {% endfor %}
];

/**
 * Function to init map
 */
function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(27.7033, 85.3224);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }

    // autocomplete the place input field 
    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
          document.getElementById('place-input'));

    var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        // infowindow.close();
        // marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
          return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
          map.setZoom(17);  
        }

            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');

    });
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var level = marker[5];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[1], marker[2]);
    var content = '<div id="infowindow">' + marker[3] + '</div>';

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        level : level,
        map: map,
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content,
    });

    infowindow.open(map, marker1);
    //marker onload listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'load', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker1);
    });

    InfoWindow1.push(infowindow);
    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
            map.setZoom(15);
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Can you please share complete code so that I can debug it from my end too. 
Regards, Suyash

Comment: I've updated my question as per your request. Thanks for trying to help. Hope you can dig out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a small code that matches with your logic of displaying markers based on category. 
Can you get some help from my code? If you have any query please comment.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>


var map;
var allMarkers = []; // All markers
var infoWindows = []; //All InfoWindows

function initialize() {
  
  //Total 5 markers
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.363882,130.044922);
  var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(-28.363882,134.044922);
  var myLatlng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(-21.363882,136.044922);
  var myLatlng5 = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.363882,138.044922);

  var locationArr = [myLatlng, myLatlng2, myLatlng3, myLatlng4, myLatlng5];

  //All infowindow content
  var contentString = '<div id="content"> ONE </div>';
  var contentString2 = '<div id="content"> TWO </div>';
  var contentString3 = '<div id="content"> THREE </div>';
  var contentString4 = '<div id="content"> FOUR </div>';
  var contentString5 = '<div id="content"> FIVE </div>';

  var contentArr = [contentString, contentString2, contentString3, contentString4, contentString5];


  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  //Adding all markers to map
  for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentArr[i]
    });  
    infoWindows.push(infowindow);
  
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: locationArr[i],
        map: map,
        title: 'This is marker '+(i+1)
    });

    //adding category as either even or odd
    if(i%2==0){
      marker['category']="odd";  
    }else{
      marker['category']="even";  
    }
    
    //pushing markers with infowindow
    allMarkers.push(marker);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 600px; width: 1000px;"></div>
    <select id="evenOdd">
      <option value="even">even</option>
      <option value="odd">odd</option>
    </select>


  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#evenOdd").change(function(){
        
        //get category from select
        var category = $(this).val();
        for(var i=0;i<allMarkers.length;i++){
          
          //If category matches, show that marker with infowindow open
          if(category == allMarkers[i].category){
            
            console.log(allMarkers[i].category);
            allMarkers[i].setVisible(true);
            infoWindows[i].open(map,allMarkers[i]);
            
          }else{
            //else, hide that marker with infowindow close
            allMarkers[i].setVisible(false);
            infoWindows[i].close();
          }
        }

      });
    })

  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks myan, Suyash!! I can relate to your code. (: